# Magento API URL doesn't exist

Tags: php, magento, soap, wsdl, magento2

I'm trying to setup a Magento API, but when I try to access the API URL I get a 404

For example, `http://localhost/magento/api` or `http://localhost/magento/api/?wsdl` go nowhere.

So when I try to connect to the server with the SoapClient I always get an error like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/magento/api/soap/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://localhost/magento/api/soap/?wsdl" in /var/www/html/magento/soapclient.php:3 .

In fact, when I can't open the WSDL XML with the browser nor access the /api endpoint.

Do I have to do anything else before get ready to work with the SOAP API?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you already solve your problem, but just to document. If you does not use CURL URL, you need to use the path to your WSDL using the

link: http://magentohost.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl